# How to develop BizTalk Server projects without a BizTalk Server installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010 and BizTalk Server 2010.
I need to uninstall BizTalk.
Is it possible to continue to use Visual Studio for BizTalk development?
If so, what do I have to do?

Comment: How would you test your code even if you could develop it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense to me - if you need to continue developing Biztalk projects, it will make life difficult without a local Biztalk (BizTalk dev edition is free and you can use SQL Express if you like). The Biztalk Deployment Framework (http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/discussions) might assist with deploying to a remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From BizTalk Server 2010 Microsoft made it completely free for development and testing purpose. Only BizTalk Server is free, not the dependant components like Visual Studio and SQL. SQL Express is not supported (http://blogs.digitaldeposit.net/saravana/post/2009/06/01/BizTalk-Server-with-SQLEXPRESS.aspx) .

You also need to keep in mind, you can use BizTalk Server with your MSDN subscription for development and testing purpose. Check it out.

Comment: +1, you are right - although local development on SQL Express is possible, it isn't a good idea (e.g. The msgbox and tracking db jobs would need to be kicked off manually, or via an @at job calling sqlcmd)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot totally uninstall BizTalk and continue to develop for BizTalk in Visual Studio, because completely uninstalling BizTalk will remove the Developer Tools and SDK. If you want to remove the BizTalk *Server* components, you can do that:

1. In your Control Panel, select *Programs and Features* or (if your settings are organized by category) select *Uninstall a program*.
2. Double-click on *Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010 Developer Edition* (assuming that the version and edition installed).
3. The Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010 Installation Wizard will open up.
4. Ensure that the *Modify* radio button is selected and press the *Next* button.
5. On the *Component Installation* page, uncheck all of the available components except for *Developer Tools and SDK*. Then press the *Next* button.
6. On the Summary page, select *Install* to proceed with the features removal.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know there is a free version of BizTalk.

nonnb's comment helped to resolve my license issue.

> This doesn't seem to make sense to me - if you need to continue developing Biztalk projects, it will make life difficult without a local Biztalk (BizTalk dev edition is free and you can use SQL Express if you like). The Biztalk Deployment Framework (biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/discussions) might assist with deploying to a remote server. – nonnb 2 days ago